# Volume form on complex space, notation

Tags: differential-geometry

If $\Omega = dz^{1}\wedge..\wedge dz^{n}$, $z^{1}$,..,$z^{n}$ are complex numbers. What does the notation $\Omega (x^{1}\wedge.. \wedge x^{n})$ means? $x^{1},..,x^{n}$ are real parts of
$z^{1}$,..,$z^{n}$. Does it mean $dx^{1}\wedge ..\wedge dx^{n}$?

Comment: In differential geometry, notational conventions vary widely. Therefore, if you ask questions about notation, you might want to provide a broader context.

Comment: Sure, there is a proposition which asserts the next:

Comment: Let $P$ be an oriented (real) vector subspace of dimension $n$ in $C^{n}$. The number $\Omega (x_{1}\wedge .. \wedge x_{n})$ depends only on $P$ and not on the positive orthonormal basis $(x_{1},..,x_{n})$ of $P$ used to express it.

Comment: Then in the proof, if we consider $2n$ vectors $(x_{1},..,x_{n},ix_{1},..,ix_{n})$ and the linear mapping $A: C^{n}\to C^{n}$ defined by the images of the vectors of the canonical basis: $A(e_{j})=x_{j}$, $A(ie_{j})=ix_{j}$, then $\Omega (x_{1},..,x_{n})=det_{C}A$.